# Append a value to a list and move all values over

Tags: python

if i start off with :

```
a=[1,2,4]
```

and i want the result to be

```
a=[1,3,2,4]
```

how do i do this append?

Comment: It's not an `append`, it's an `insert`. `Append` s go at the end.

Comment: To expound, append (as opposed to prepend), means--by definition--"to insert at the *end*."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`a.insert( 1, 3 )`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.insert)

Answer (score 6):

```
In [18]: a=[1,2,4]

In [19]: a[1:1]=[3]

In [20]: a
Out[20]: [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

or

```
In [22]: a.insert(1,3)

In [24]: a
Out[24]: [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

With the first (slice) notation, you can even insert multiple elements (similar to `extend`, but not necessarily at the end of the list):

```
In [26]: a[1:1]=[3,5]

In [27]: a
Out[27]: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

whereas with the `insert` method, you can only insert one element:

```
In [30]: a.insert(1,[3,5])

In [31]: a
Out[31]: [1, [3, 5], 2, 4]
```

The slice notation can also be used to modify or remove parts of a list.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the [slice operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#slicings):

```
a[1:1] = (3,)
```

Or with the [insert function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
a.insert(1, 3)
```

In both cases, position `1` refers to the second slot in the list.